# Can a closed manifold defines a submersion over a manifold with non-empty boundary?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I would like to know if there are submersions $\pi : F\hookrightarrow M\to B$ (with fiber $F$) from a closed manifold $M$ to a manifold $B$ with boundary.

I really suspect that the answer is no, since $M$ is compact it is possible to trivialize $\pi$ (in the sense of fiber bundles trivializations). So it would imply that $B$ can't have boundary.

Comment: I wonder what $F$ is.

Comment: @mfl it is just the fiber of the submersion.

Comment: No. A hint: each submersion $R^n\to R^m$ is an open mapping.